# Launch camera activity over lock screen

Tags: android, camera, lockscreen, android-camera-intent

I have an activity that acts similar to the Facebook Cover Feed (Shows over the lock screen). As you can see Facebook Cover Feed provides a feature to launch the camera by swiping to the left. However, the camera could be launched over the lock screen normally!

What I want to know is how can I open the device camera application over the lock screen the same as Facebook Cover Feed does.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to call for the camera activity use the following in API 17+ *I didn't find an alternative for older versions*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
```

Comment: Work for me :) did u able to find alternative for below 17